# ActiveRecord where results incorrect when rendered in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Rails version 6, postgresql v 11, ruby 2.7.0**

I'm struggling with strange behaviour when using ActiveRecord to populate an HTML table in the view based on a search field contained in a form.

If I request the base URL

```
localhost:3000/instui/search
```

I get a results which contains (correctly) the first 20 records from the database (securities from the NYSE and NASDAQ):

[image]

If I put say BB in the search field, I can see the "where" has done its job and just retrieved the corresponding records from the puts to the console:

```
Processing by InstuiController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"BB", "commit"=>"Search"}
{"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Search", "q"=>"BB"}
  Instrument Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "instruments".* FROM "instruments" WHERE (ticker LIKE '%BB%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 20]]
  ↳ app/controllers/instui_controller.rb:19:in `search'
Asia Broadband Inc
ABB Ltd
Auburn Bancorp Inc
AbraPlata Resource Corp
AB DISCOVERY VALUE FUND CLASS B
AbbVie Inc
Abby Inc
AB GROWTH FUND CLASS B
Ambu A/S
Mercantil Bank Holding Corporation
BAB Inc
BlackBerry Limited
New York Health Care Inc
NORTHERN GLOBAL TACTICAL ASSET ALLOCATION FUND NORTHERN GLOBAL TACTICAL ASSET ALLOCATION FUND
BBA Aviation plc
BBA Aviation plc
JPMorgan BetaBuilders Dev Asia ex-JpnETF
BBH LIMITED DURATION FUND CLASS I SHARES
Baker Boyer Bancorp
BlueBird Battery Metals Inc
20
  Rendering instui/search.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered instui/search.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 339)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 11.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 11355)
```

However the view continues to render the same result from the previous request - i.e. all of the records as if the view hasn't received the new instance variable from the controller. I cannot see where I'm going wrong. Help appreciated.

[image]

The View is:

```
<h2>Search</h2>
  <%= form_with(url: "search", method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <% end %>



<table class="table table-striped">

<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Country</th><th>Ticker</th>

<%  @search_results.each do |i| %>
<tr>  

<td><%= i.id %></td>                         
<td><%= i.name %></td>  
<td><%= i.country  %></td>
<td><%= i.ticker  %></td>
</tr>           
<% end %>       

</table>
```

Controller is:

```
class InstuiController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end


  def search

    @searchTerms = params.permit(:utf8, :commit, :q)

        puts(@searchTerms)

        query  = @searchTerms[:q]

        if query == nil 
                query = "%%"
        end

        @search_results = Instrument.where("ticker LIKE ?",  "%#{query}%").limit(20)
        @search_results.each { |i| puts(i.name) }
        puts @search_results.length

  end   

end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'test/index'
  get 'instui/index'
  get 'instui/search'
  get 'assetmaster/csvlist'
  resources :instruments


    get 'instruments/csvlist'
    get 'prices/priceservice'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: On the first line of that log statement it says `Processing by InstuiController#search as JS` which would explain why nothing is happening but not why you are not getting a missing template error. If you are using `form_with` make sure to pass the `local: true` option.

Comment: @max Thanks so much. This solved the problem, if you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself, I already have a few thousand.

Answer (score 2):

OK so the problem was I had not set `local: true` on the form. Form rewritten as:

```
<%= form_with(url: "search", method: "get", local: true) do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

And the problem disappears.